# How to test the newly added functionality in a Joomla 2.5 site which is live

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jumi

I am working on a dynamic site on Joomla!, most of the coding is done in Juni module and component.

I have some dynamic features which **I want to test it on my already published site**, I fear that if any thing goes wrong by attaching it to the published site.

I want to  ask is there any modules of plugins for Joomla! which allows me to test my dynamic functionality on the published site, and Is there any extension to recover my site to previous state(like version control system of my site...)

Answer (score 0):

Where is a quick checklist with what you can do:

- The easiest way to play around is to [install Joomla! on your own computer](http://docs.joomla.org/Use_Joomla!_on_your_own_computer) where you can test everything without any worries
- To get your websites like "versioned" or to have a complete backup, the most used and trusted solution is [AkeebaBackup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/).
- My advice would be **NOT to play directly with the live website** without doing a backup, especially if you are "testing" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it makes more sense to test first on a copy that is in the exact same server environment as the live site.

How to test live is always a hard thing, sooner or later you have to do it, but you want to get as much testing done as you can without doing it. Depending on how the feature is being rendered you may be able to use acl to prevent it being rendered to normal users.